# Using .tpl.php templates instead of Twig templates

Tags: theming, 8

Is there a way to use .tpl.php templates instead of Twig templates in Drupal 8, or is there a way to write PHP in a Twig file instead of that Twig language?

I am a beginner for Drupal 8, but I have worked with Drupal 7.

Comment: No you can’t write php in a Twig file, it’s a different language. The “annoying” language is Twig itself, nothing to do with Symfony other than Symfony happens to prefer it (not least because it’s miles ahead of old php-only templates). If you need php logic to prepare variables for a template file, that’s what preprocess functions were made for, same as D7

Comment: So can I call php functions from the twig language? @Clive

Comment: You could plug-in the phptemplate engine as service. Have a look at hook_extensions() and hook_theme(). But I would not recommend this at all. You should do all logic in preprocess functions and template should solely for displaying the information without any data manipulation. The old phptemplateengine-way was really bad.

Comment: Not directly, but you can write [extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) to expose them, yes

Comment: Is there a bot or something that rakes this site and downvotes everything? Seeing a _ton_ of downvotes lately on questions and answers.

Comment: @Kevin It's understandable on questions, downvotes are supposed to be given for a lack of effort. No offence aimed at anyone in particular, but it's quite rare to see good research presented in a question. So plenty of questions with downvotes is to be expected. Answers not so much, feel free to raise a flag if you want us to see if the system has spotted any unusual activity

Comment: You can convert your Twig code to PHP or TPL here : https://www.easycodetools.com/tool/twig-to-php-converter here, is online twig to PHP converter ( online twig to TPL converter )

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write PHP in twig files. [Twig is fairly expressive](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/) to the degree in which you need to template, for everything else, it should go into the .theme file, theme hook, and/or preprocess function.

There is virtually no reason to have PHP code in a template.

Spend a week with Twig and you won't go back.

Example:

```
<?php if ($page['content']): ?>
  <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

vs:

```
{% if page.content %}
  {{ page.content }}
{% endif %}
```

Much more readable.

I'll expand with a more advanced example.

Lets say you have list of things you want to output, but every 7 items, you want to make a new unordered list. The end goal is the CSS inlines these lists, think of a superfish menu where menu links are ordered top to bottom, then left to right.

```
  <div class="global-top__submenu">
    {% for chunk in items|batch(7) %}
      <ul class="global-top__submenu-col">
        {% for item in chunk %}
          <li>
            {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Where `items` is passed to the template. This small example will output a UL with 7 items until there is nothing left to print.

[image]

I have yet to run into an instance where I *cannot* accomplish something with Twig, or, *because* it's Twig.

Give it a shot and dive in, forget phptemplate.

Comment: Is there a reason this is downvoted?

Comment: Seems like a fair answer to me, maybe downvoted because someone was not happy with this answer?

Comment: Hi @Kevin this explains a lot. Thanks ! Could you please elaborate how to get the details of a child page from a parent page node in twig. I have done that with tpl in D7. But don't know how to get it with twig.

Answer (score 2):

To use custom PHP and display the result in a template, you must go through preprocessing functions (like `hook_preprocess_node()`) to override the display or add new variables to display in your template. You can create a custom module or use the MYTEHEME.theme file of your current theme to call preprocessing function.

If before you used a lot of PHP code in TPL files, it's bad practice because the files are used to display the data not to make hard particular/specific  treatments inside.